# Validar um array de TextBox em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, javascript-eventos

Olá minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho uma funcao de js assim:

```
function testeCampos(elemento) {

//Recebe lista de campos para valida��o 
var camposArray = new Array();
camposArray = elemento;

//Recebe campo armazenado no array
var campo, recFocu;

//Verifica se h� uma ocorrencia de erro 
var faltaPre = false

//varre o Array de Campos 
for (c = 0; c < camposArray.length; c++) {

    //cria Objeto com o metodo DOM
    campo = document.getElementById(camposArray[c]);

    if (campo.value == '') {

        campo.style.backgroundColor = "#eeee99";

        if (faltaPre != true) {
            faltaPre = true;
            recFocu = campo;
        }
    }
    else {
        campo.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}

if (faltaPre == true) {
    alert('Campo com Preenchimento obrigat\xf3rio!!!');
    recFocu.focus();
    return false;
}
else {
    return true;
}
}
```

recebe como parâmetro um array de textbox e vai validando uma por uma

estou montando o array no page_load da pagina assim:

```
TextBox[] aTextbox = { txtNome, TxtEndereco, TxtCEP, TxtBairro, TxtUF, TxtCidade, TxtTelefone, txtUsuario, TxtSenha };
```

e acionando o evento onClick no CodeBehind assim:

```
this.btnEnviar.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return testeCampos(aTextbox);");
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem algum erro no meu code? pois está dando erro no JS

[CODIGO DA PAGE CADASTRO](https://github.com/antoniofs/OVERFLOW)

Comment: O seu array TextBox[], não deveria ser um string[] com os ids dos campos?

Comment: Fiz e o erro continua string[] aTextbox = { txtNome.ID, TxtEndereco.ID };

Comment: Mas sempre eu envio um objeto textBox, por isso criei o array de textBox

Comment: Obs: erro 0x800a1391 - Erro em tempo de execução do JavaScript: 'aTextbox' não está definido

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta com mais detalhes, com a página ou view completa.

Comment: A ideia é ele percorrer textBox por textBox o primeiro campo vazio ele deveria dá focus no banco em branco e pronto.

Comment: posta a página, se não vai ser só advinhação... como por exemplo aTextBox é um objeto server side... ele não foi escrito na tela e por isso não existe no escopo do javascript

Comment: Opa, desculpe leandro atualizei com um link do git tem a minha page de cadastro :(

Comment: Obrigado leandro, conseguir, vou deixa a minha resposta para membros com dúvida ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom primeiro você precisa pegar o textbox no front no caso no HTML
como por exemplo:

```
 function testarCampos() {

         var arrayCampos = []; //Array de Objetos
         arrayCampos[0] = document.forms[0].NOME_DO_OBJETO
         arrayCampos[1] = document.forms[0].TxtEndereco;
     }
```

Depois você passa para essa sua função

```
testeCampos(arrayCampos)
```

Bem, sua função volta true ou false então dá para comparar

então faça um if, assim

```
         if (testeCampos(arrayCampos) == true) {
             return true;
         }else
         {
             return false;
         }
```

Código Completo

```
         function testarCampos() {

         var arrayCampos = [];
         arrayCampos[0] = document.forms[0].txtNome;
         arrayCampos[1] = document.forms[0].TxtEndereco;
         arrayCampos[2] = document.forms[0].TxtCEP;
         arrayCampos[3] = document.forms[0].TxtBairro;
         arrayCampos[4] = document.forms[0].TxtTelefone;
         arrayCampos[5] = document.forms[0].txtUsuario;
         arrayCampos[4] = document.forms[0].TxtSenha;

         //alert(arrayCampos[0].value);

         if (testeCampos(arrayCampos) == true) {
             return true;
         }else
         {
             return false;
         }


     }
```